# Как изменить proxy в selenium?

Tags: python, proxy, selenium-webdriver

Программа выполняется, терминал не ругается, удается поменять `user-agent`, но `ip` остается прежним:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http', '151.80.156.147')
profile.set_preference('network.proxy.http_port', 8080)
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Opera/9.80 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X; U; en) Presto/2.6 Version/10.63")
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://2ip.ru/')
time.sleep(3)
driver.close()
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Answer (score 0):

добавьте переменную окружения, например

```
export http_proxy="http://151.80.156.147:8080"
```